# Unity и RigidBody

Tags: c#, unity3d

как заставить RigidBody разгоняться до определенной скорости,
как правильно прикладывать силу. двигаю танчик. И можно ли использовать transform.Translate с ригидбоди

Comment: эту проблему я решил, но появилась другая, объект может вращаться только когда он совершает поступательное движение, а должен просто вращаться еще и на месте вокруг своей оси, использую метод AddRelativeTorque()